# Vim: opening a buffer that I don't want to write to

Tags: vim, diff

I just created a new mapping in my .vimrc to quickly open the diff of the repository I'm working in in a new window.

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                                                
" Quickly see diff
" """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Open /tmp/tmp.diff in a new split
" delete the entire content
" read in the diff
nnoremap <leader>d :vsp /tmp/tmp.diff<CR>ggdG<bar>:r !hg diff<CR>
" Automatically write the diff when exiting the buffer so we're not asked to
" save it
autocmd! BufUnload /tmp/tmp.diff :w<CR>
```

As you can see I use the BufUnload autocmd to save the file when exiting the buffer because I don't want to manually write to it every time I view the diff. But I'd rather have Vim not warn me.

So is there a way to open a buffer in Vim that does not care if it's closed when it has unsaved content? I'd also like it if I would not have to open a specific file, rather an anonymous buffer.

I'd rather not use autowrite.

(I'm just a beginner in Vim/Vimscript so if I should write a function for this please tell me)

Answer (score 5):

I have this in such buffers:

```
setlocal buftype=nofile noswapfile bufhidden=delete
```

For example, my hotkey for running `git diff` on the current file (the diff output is kept in such a buffer):

```
function Git_diff(fil)
    abo new
    exe '0read ++ff=unix !git diff -- ' . a:fil
    setlocal noma ro ts=8 tw=0 nowrap syn=diff ft=diff
    setlocal buftype=nofile noswapfile bufhidden=delete
    go
endfunction
map <f3> :call Git_diff(expand("%"))<CR>gg
```